# DB2: UNWRAP function for PL/SQL Code?

Tags: db2, plsqldeveloper, db2-luw

I am using DB2 LUW version 10.5 version. The PL/SQL code I have is wrapped. Is there a tool to unwrap the code to readable format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WRAPPED` code is a security feature to protect intellectual property of those who created function, procedures and views. Using the functionality of the DB2 [module DBMS_DDL](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0057137.html) it is possible to create such wrapped or obfuscated code. There is no documented or shipped tool to unwrap the code, else the security feature would be worthless.